# In react.js functional component, how does onClick or any event work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning react.js functional components and I came with the method `useState()`. Which gives an array in return `[currentState, stateSetter]`. Now if we use `stateSetter()` in an event. And we know that events are called differently. So how does it access the `handleClick()` function. Since it is not defined inside the scope?

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function App(props) {
  
  const [name, setName] = useState("name1");
  
  const handleClick = () => {
    setName("name2");
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Hello, {name}</p>
      <button onClick = {handleClick}></button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not defined inside the scope?

Comment: The above code works perfectly I just don't know how it works. In class components when we wanted to use any method we used to bind that to value of `this` so we can use the methods inside class when any event occurs. Because when events are called they are called differently and from my example the `handleClick()` is defined inside of `App()` so it is not available outside of `App()`. So how does `onClick()` access the `handleClick()`.

Comment: setName is defined in a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) which binds it to the lexical environment of handleClick and can therefore be accessed inside the onClick callback.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple because your are passing to the `onClick` function a reference to the function which you have define and save as value of variable named `handleClick`. As long as JS can resolve the reference of that variable the function or the value which that variable references will be executed.

That is the same with **classes Component** when we pass `this.handleClick` to an `onClick` props of a tag, we are just passing the reference to that function.

Answer (score 0):

Because unlike Class bases components functional components do not have instance so there is no need to use this or binding functions inside it while using.

Here is another answer you might want to check out: [functional component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44478942/5669120)